# What is the .container width in bootstrap for IE8?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, width

I need to know what is the .container width in bootstrap for IE8 since it doesn't support media queries and the framework has both medium and large screen versions of the .container with media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, if a browser doesn't understand media queries then it looks to me like the would be the governing rule for the container, i.e., no fixed width

```
.container {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px
}
```